# Problem in woocommerce.The option "Add product image" is gone.Please help me!

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm not able to add product image in my site. This is really a big problem for me. Please help me[image: The option is gone,I found everywhere]

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the screen is a tab with screen options. Click it and it will open up. Check to see if Product gallery and product image checkboxes are checked.